# Incorrect work of jQuery function .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all the text from HTML without any tags by using `$('.container').text()`. Instead of getting clear text I get text with duplicate parts.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="v highlighted" id="4">
    <span class="vn" id="4">4</span>
    <span class="p">Text-0</span><br>
    <span class="p">
        <span class="wj">
            Text-1
            <span class="w">Text-2</span>
            Text-3
        </span>
    </span><br>
</div>

<script>
    console.log($(".highlighted :not(.vn)").text());
</script>
```

In the console I see this result:

```
Text-0Text-1Text-2Text-3Text-1Text-2Text-3Text-2
```

Does anybody know why it happens?

Comment: The output seems correct. What are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting Text-0Text-1Text-2Text-3

Comment: See Quentin's answer for a full explanation of what is happening here, and how to get your desired result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at what `.highlighted :not(.vn)` matches.

It matches:

- `<span class="p">Text-0</span>`
- `<br>`
- `<span class="p"><span class="wj">Text-1<span class="w">Text-2</span>Text-3</span></span>`
- `<span class="wj">Text-1<span class="w">Text-2</span>Text-3</span>`
- `<span class="w">Text-2</span>`
- `<br>`

Since you have some text contained in a span which is contained in another span and **both** those spans match the selector, you get the content of the outer span **and** the (identical) content of the inner span.

You probably want to use a child combinator (`>`) instead of a descendant combinator () in your selector.

```
.highlighted > :not(.vn)
```

Comment: You forget this match `<span class="w">Text-2</span>`

Answer (score -1):

It may help you:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="v highlighted" id="4">
<span class="vn" id="4">4</span>
<span class="p">Text-0</span>
<br>
<span class="p"><span class="wj">Text-1<span class="w">Text-2</span>Text-3</span></span>
<br>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(".highlighted span:not(.vn)").each(function(){
        console.log("--",$(this).text());
    });

});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```